# Editing workflow mail before sending SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, email

Is there any possibility to edit workflow mial before sending?

I would like to achive that workflow first open mail window and I will able to edit this mail then I click "Send" in for example Outlook window and then mail will send.

Thanks for any help and support,
Andrzej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you'll be able to get to that with an ootb workflow is to create a workflow that has initiation parameters. When initiated, this will prompt the user for information on a separate workflow initiation form. You can then merge this information into the email that gets sent.

Comment: Are you able to tell me how to initiation parameters by workflow?

Comment: There is a link in the ribbon called initiation form paramemters. Using that you can create the parameters you need. Then when users initiate the workflow, they are prompted for the information via the initiation form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found but if workflow will have a few actions which will be first? initiation form or workflow actions?

Comment: Initiation form happens first, then all the actions.